# How to install omniORB on Windows?

Tags: windows, compilation, installation, omniorb

I installed Python and MinGW, added everything which is needed to PATH (g++ and python), and downloaded omniORB from http://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORB/omniORB-4.1.6/omniORB-4.1.6.tar.bz2/download, unzipped it.

I cded to omniORB directory but there were no omniORB binaries in \bin\x86_win32 directory.

So I have 2 questions:

1) where can I get omniORB binaries? (I would like to install omniORB on my computer with Windows XP/Vista (both x86))

2) is it possible to install omniORB from source when I have only MinGW installed (no Visual C++)? **How to do this** (I need steps)?

Comment: find the README.win32.txt in your sourcces, there  is a description how to build.

Comment: @pbhd: I found it already but still - dont know how to install it with only MinGW installed

Comment: Have you asked google about that? Found that one: http://www.omniorb-support.com/pipermail/omniorb-list/2010-June/030652.html, so what you are trying to do seems to be not that trivial.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already installed Python, MinGW and added environment settings also,

You need to do the following things.

1. Go the unzipped folder of OmniORB ( I assume it is there in C:\OmniORB)
2. Open the src folder, where you can find the make files
3. Compile it with the MinGW(gcc) compiler which you have installed already

Answer for Question 1:
Once the compilation is done, you will get the OmniORB binary, if it is not found in bin folder.

Answer for Question 2:
Once you unzipped, it internally means you have installed. It doesn't have any setup.exe files externally.

Since you have MinGW make use of gcc compiler in it.