# How to install omniORB and omniORBpy on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, corba, omniorb

**Context**

I need to install omniORB and omniORBpy on Windows 10 to use Python 3.7 as Server Skeleton and a Java Stub as client.

I have already installed omniORB and omniORBpy in Ubuntu LTS 18.04 and I have a small system made. It works perfectly,  but it is only compatible with Python 2.7 and I need it to be Python 3.7.

[This is what the system I did looks like (it's in Spanish, sorry for that)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue7Uj.png)

**What I have tried**

First, I tried copying the omniORBpy files (omniORB, CORBA.py, etc) from my Python 2.7 Ubuntu venv to the venv of my Python 2.7 in Windows. Just to try.

PyCharm recognizes the venv libraries but when I run the script, it says that I can not find the file "_omnipy" (and I guess other files that it still does not tell me). I realized that this library used * .so files (obviously) and that I needed it maybe it was a type of * .dll to work with Windows.

[This is my Python 2.7 venv (site-packages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvLTa.png)

[This is the error what I get on PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qscls.png)

On the other hand, I still can not find how to install omniORB to use the omniNames service and have the IOR (on Windows) and use omniidl to "compile" my idl file.

I need something like

```
sudo omniNames -start 2809
```

on Windows cmd (not on a subsystem of Linux installed on Windows).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I recommend you search Stack Overflow before posting; you'll often find that someone has answered your question previously.

Secondly, I recommend you read the included readme file from [omniORB 4.2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORB/omniORB-4.2.0/). There are installation instructions for Win32 and Win64 platforms.

Lastly, refer to this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484978/how-to-install-omniorb-on-windows), it may offer additional help.